# How to resolve ambiguity between constructors taking std::string and std::vector

Tags: c++, overloading, ambiguous-call

I want to make a "Tag" class that can have its name specified either as a dot separated name like `"this.is.my.name"` or as a vector of strings, like `{"this","is","my","name"}`.

When I try to do this, I am **sometimes** getting told by the compiler that my calls are ambiguous.  I want to know (1) why this is ambiguous at all, and (2) why it is only ambiguous sometimes.

Here is my example code, which you can also view and compile [here on Coliru](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/2871bfc868d2d0dc)

```
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

class Tag
{
public:
    explicit Tag(std::string name);
    explicit Tag(std::vector<std::string> name);

};

Tag::Tag(std::string name)
{
    //here 'name' will be a dotted collection of strings, like "a.b.c"
}

Tag::Tag(std::vector<std::string> name)
{
    //here 'name' will be a vector of strings, like {"a","b","c"}
}


int main(int argc, char**argv)
{
    Tag imaTag{{"dotted","string","again"}};
    Tag imaTagToo{"dotted.string"};

    //everything is fine without this line:
    Tag imaTagAlso{{"dotted","string"}};
    std::cout << "I made two tags" << std::endl;

}
```

With the indicated line, I get the following error:

```
g++ -std=c++11 -O2 -Wall -pthread main.cpp && ./a.out
main.cpp: In function 'int main(int, char**)':
main.cpp:28:39: error: call of overloaded 'Tag(<brace-enclosed initializer list>)' is ambiguous
     Tag imaTagAlso{{"dotted","string"}};
                                   ^
main.cpp:18:1: note: candidate:     'Tag::Tag(std::vector<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> >)'
 Tag::Tag(std::vector<std::string> name)
 ^~~
main.cpp:13:1: note: candidate: 'Tag::Tag(std::__cxx11::string)'
 Tag::Tag(std::string name)
 ^~~
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`Tag imaTagAlso{{"dotted","string"}};`  says construct a `Tag`, call it `imaTagAlso` and initialize it with `{"dotted","string"}`.  The issue with that is `std::string` can be constructed by a pair of iterators and since string literals can decay to `const char*`'s, they qualify as iterators.  So you could either call the string constructor using the "iterators", or you could call the vector constructor using its `std::initializer_list` constructor.  To work around this you can use

```
Tag imaTagAlso{{{"dotted"},{"string"}}};
```

which says  construct a `Tag`, call it `imaTagAlso` and initialize it with `{{"dotted"},{"string"}}` and now `{"dotted"}` and `{"string"}` become elements of the `std::initializer_list` for the vector constructor.

You could also (since c++14) use [`std::string`'s user defined literal operator (`""s`)](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/operator%22%22s) like

```
Tag imaTagAlso{{"dotted"s,"string"s}};
```

which makes each element of the *braced-init-list* `std::string`'s, and the vector constructor will be chosen.

Comment: Or may be just put a proper type there - could be more straightforward than 3 curly braces.

Comment: @SergeyA Good idea.  I've added a way using `std::string`'s `operator ""s`

Comment: Yep, brilliant. Just probably a line break after `vector constructor` and before `You could also use`?

Comment: @SergeyA Updated.

Comment: In C++11, you could use `std::string` explicitly: `Tag imaTagAlso{{std::string("dotted"),std::string("string")}};`